# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I am getting the above error and I am not aware what is causing this. Please do help me to debug the error. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

My Main Activity method (I have named it as DetailsUsers.Java)

```
      package form.app.applicationform1;

        import form.app.applicationform1.DatabaseHandler;
        import form.app.applicationform1.R;
        import form.app.applicationform1.User;



        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class DetailsUsers  extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
            private static String position = null;



            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                Intent intent = getIntent();

                position = intent.getStringExtra("position");
                Log.d("value of position from intent", position);
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
                User user = db.getUser(position);
                TextView textViewDetailName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                textViewDetailName.setText(user.getName());

                TextView textViewDetailAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                textViewDetailAddress.setText(user.getAddress());

                TextView textViewDetailsPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                textViewDetailsPhone.setText(user.getPhone());

                TextView textViewDetailsEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                textViewDetailsEmail.setText(user.getEmail());

                TextView textViewDetailsComments = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                textViewDetailsComments.setText(user.getComments());

                Button backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                backButton.setOnClickListener(this);

                Button editButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                editButton.setOnClickListener(this);

                Button saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
                saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListUsers.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditUsers.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", position);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (v.getId() == R.id.button3){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsUsers.class);
                    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "User Has Been Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    intent.putExtra("position", position);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
```

Main.xml file:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="form.app.applicationform1.DetailsUsers" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/back" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/form_icon"
            android:paddingLeft="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:tag="Edit Form" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="@string/full_name"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/phone_no"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/email_id"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/postal_address"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/comments_feedback"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/edit_form" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save_form" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="form.app.applicationform1"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name="form.app.applicationform1.DetailsUsers"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".EditUsers"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_users" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ListUsers"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_list_users" >
            </activity>

             <activity android:name="form.app.applicationform1.DatabaseHandler"></activity>
            <activity android:name="form.app.applicationform1.User"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Logcat error trace:

```
        12-23 01:29:29.179: D/AndroidRuntime(2412): Shutting down VM
        12-23 01:29:29.219: W/dalvikvm(2412): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f5e648)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{form.app.applicationform1/form.app.applicationform1.DetailsUsers}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at form.app.applicationform1.DetailsUsers.onCreate(DetailsUsers.java:28)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        12-23 01:29:29.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2412):     ... 11 more
```

Database code is as below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userDB";
    // Employee table name
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

    private static String NAME = "name";
    private static String PHONE = "phone";
    private static String EMAIL  = "email";
    private static String ADDRESS = "address";
    private static String COMMENTS = "comments";
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "("
                + NAME + " TEXT,"
                + PHONE + " TEXT,"
                + EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + ADDRESS + " TEXT"
                + COMMENTS + " TEXT"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        //db.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

    // Adding new user
    public int addUser(User user) 
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(ADDRESS, user.getAddress());
        values.put(PHONE, user.getPhone());
        values.put(EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COMMENTS, user.getComments());
        // Inserting Row
        int id = (int) db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        return id;
    }

    //updating a existing user
    public int editUser(User user, String position) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(NAME, user.getName());
            values.put(ADDRESS, user.getAddress());
            values.put(PHONE, user.getPhone());
            values.put(EMAIL, user.getEmail());
            values.put(COMMENTS, user.getComments());
            // updating row
            return db.update(TABLE_USERS, values, NAME + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(position) });
    }

    public User getUser(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[] { 
                NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE, EMAIL, COMMENTS }, NAME + "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        User user = new User(cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;

    }

        // LIst all users
        public String[] getAllUsers() {
            ArrayList<String> usersList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
            try {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                // looping through all rows and adding to list
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String user = cursor.getString(1) + ", " + cursor.getString(2) +  ", " + cursor.getString(3) + ", " + cursor.getString(4) + ", " + cursor.getString(5);
                        usersList.add(user);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

                String[] users = new String[usersList.size()];
                db.close();
                return (usersList.toArray(users));
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error in getting users from DB", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

}
```

Please let me know if more information is needed. Please help to solve this problem

Comment: probably `position` is null and issue is occuring due to second parameter is null in `Log.d("value of position from intent", position);`

Comment: Try to use it in this way.
Log.d("value of position from intent", ""+position);

Comment: Changed the Log.d statement and got the below error:
12-23 02:07:32.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2577):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 02:07:32.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2577): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: comments (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, address, phone, email, comments FROM users WHERE name=?

Error is in my database.. Can I get suggestions for this please..

Comment: @keshavkowshik post your database activity. Error is in there ..

Comment: @Darkie I have posted my database code just now.

Comment: @keshavkowshik I have answered the question probably you are entering the query wrong ...

Comment: @keshavkowshik 1- you are using Log.d() incorrectly, check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) 2- if your question was solved mark it as answered, and ask new question about the new issue, now title talks about Null, and in comments you are asking about db-missing column ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the query like this and then try. you are missing a comma after address text and put space after the comma ... :)

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "("
            + NAME + " TEXT, "
            + PHONE + " TEXT, "
            + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
            + COMMENTS + " TEXT "
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
```

Hope it helps ...

Comment: Changed it, now its is displaying an error from SQL Log as shown below:

Comment: Changed it, now its is displaying an error from SQL Log as shown below:
D/value of position from intent(2667): null
E/SQLiteLog(2667): (1) no such column: comments
D/AndroidRuntime(2667): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(2667): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f5e648)
E/AndroidRuntime(2667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2667): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: Continued error message:
ComponentInfo{form.app.applicationform1/form.app.applicationform1.DetailsUsers}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: comments (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, address, phone, email, comments FROM users WHERE name=?

I am new to coding please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I have posted it now.

Comment: @keshavkowshik ok I am posting there tutorials for you go through them. it will give you the idea how to deal with the databases in android. you are also writing the query wrong in the select statement. these tutorials are easy to understand and they will help you ... :)
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Comment: That error message has vanished now. there was error in querying thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a) Please add null result error handling for:

```
position = intent.getStringExtra("position");
```

b) Also, when you insert your Extras consider adding .toString()

c) Always use something like Log.d("value of position from intent", ""+position) if you don't check for position == null OR you could write your own Log.d wrapper which accepts and handles nulls.

Comment: Added try catch for:
position = intent.getStringExtra("position");

Got the below error after this:

 D/value of position from intent(2667): null
 E/SQLiteLog(2667): (1) no such column: comments
 D/AndroidRuntime(2667): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(2667): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f5e648)
 E/AndroidRuntime(2667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(2667): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: Continued error message:

ComponentInfo{form.app.applicationform1/form.app.applicationform1.DetailsUsers}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: comments (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, address, phone, email, comments FROM users WHERE name=?

I am new to coding please help me.

Comment: It looks like the table still is missing the column "comments".  I see you posted this 14 minutes ago but 28 minutes ago another user pointed out you were also missing a comma in '+ ADDRESS + " TEXT"' which would prevent you from having this column.

Comment: @ William Deans I have fixed that. But still I am getting this error.

Comment: Is it possible the new table create is failing because a bad table is already in place?  Add some log statement before "db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);"

Comment: Pardon me. Did not understand.

Comment: If the column is still missing are you sure that the old users table has been removed and a new (correct) table created?  Can you check to make certain?

Comment: Added log statements. Those log statements did not appear in logcat trace. I am not understanding why am I getting this error.

Comment: If they didn't appear onUpgrade isn't called and therefore the old table is still in place with the missing column.

Comment: Ok will do some research on this.

Comment: Thanks William for all your help.